# How do I not have a duplicated custom bash script directory on my machine and add it as a link that is picked up with PATH?

Tags: bash, path, linker

I have a `/.cust_dev_cmds/` directory on my MBP machine that is part of a parent sysadmin-work directory that uses a git repo [here](https://github.com/rolandrgarceau/sysadmin-work/tree/master/bash-syntax-and-usage). I would like to be able to:

1. Not have to use a for loop in my .bash_profile to source all the *.sh files.
2. Add the directory to PATH with and export line in the .bash_profile instead.

```sh
# from my .bash_profile
export PATH="/Users/<my-usr-name>/Public/sharable-dev-scripts:$PATH"
```

This does show up with a `echo $PATH` but when I try to invoke a function from within the scripts I have created that worked with sourcing directly within the .bash_profile in a loop (like with point #1 above) like this

```sh
# create a directory with a builtin command
mkdir test-dir
# use one of my custom ones to create a simple readme.md within that directory:
mkr !!:1
# I am getting >>> mkr: command not found
```

3. Use whatever type of link to not have a duplicated directory structure on the machine.

   - Any good explanations to read up on here without using $10 words would be great.
4. Define a means to test the link works and works through PATH. It would also be nice that something like `declare -F` would be available to see that the scripts within the directory are in fact becoming part of callable functions in the shell.

   - is there a command anyone knows to do this?
5. Step this up a notch for a shared network directory. I have created a shared directory through apple > System Preferences > Sharing, and turned on the ability to share this directory in the Public folder.

   - Is there a tutorial that can outline this with something like VirtualBox and an Ubuntu guest that is accessing the commands from the MBP shared directory?

I have realized point #1, so really the question begins with #2 so no one would suggest the first one. I have read a bit on links but the way most of the articles I come across describing them are difficult to wrap my head around- especially when wishing to add this functionality to PATH. I believe the answer may revolve around how links are followed, but it may be better to back up and punt- dig back into linking first- then export my directory appropriately without a link, and eventually get the proper resolution to this situation.

The last thought on links before I try a few hacks on my own is do I need to only add a link to the Public directory and somehow place a flag to look at all the directories within the /Public, or is it better to drill all the way down to the /Public/shared-directory/.cust_dev_cmds? Any direction would be greatly appreciated. My goal is to be able to have a few custom command directories for various tasks, and eventually have them across networks/instances.

Answer (score 1):

When you want all functions that you wrote in files in `/.cust_dev_cmds/`, the normal way would be sourcing all the files.
When you  want to avoid a loop, you can use

```
utildir="$HOME/.cust_dev_cmds/" # I think the path is relative to your home).
source <(cat ${utildir}/*)
```

When you want the functions found with the PATH, you should make a file for each function.

Before:

```
# cat talk
ask() { echo "How are you?"; }
answer() { echo "Fine, thank you"; }
```

After:

```
# cat ask
echo "How are you?"

# cat answer
echo "Fine, thank you"
```

When you want all users to use the same set of functions, consider a master script that sources all scripts (the masterfile can use user=dependent settings like HOME or VERSION):

```
# cat /Public/shared-directory/setup_functions
utildir="$HOME/.cust_dev_cmds/" # I think the path is relative to your home).
source <(cat ${utildir}/*)
source some_other_file
```

Now each user only needs to source one file.

Comment: Not clear with what? Add `source /Public/shared-directory/setup_functions` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and document which default variables can be changed, like `my_branch`, `git_user` and `HOME`.

Comment: I did not get the edit complete. I am using a .bash_profile and the clarity has to do with sourcing and adding export Path= both into the .bash_profile. I would like to know if i can do one or the other. I have been testing more than just that an need to narrow focus to one specific problem- understanding how .bashrc works with .bash_profile

Comment: Addressing your offer of ```When you want the functions found with the PATH, you should make a file for each function.``` I also need to know if the shell can only find one function per script or can I have a list of functions?

Comment: Functions in a script are unknown when they are not loaded, that is why you should `source` them. Files that are executable can be found by `PATH`. You can not do something like `call filename:function` (or you write a fancy function `call` that searches for the function in the given filename).
Add `echo "Sourced .bashrc"` and `echo "Sourced .bash_profile"` in .bash_rc and .bash_profile and test it by calling `bash` and `bash --login`. You should not define environment variables in ~/.bashrc : see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/57293